# Call to undefined method PDO execute

Tags: php, pdo

I've get this error on the page. What can be the problem.. I've checked tons of thread here with the same problem and can't figured it out.

```
$ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$vote_rank = 0;
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT SUM(vote_rank) as vote_rank FROM ipaddress_vote_map WHERE image_id = ? and ip_address = ?");
$query -> bindParam(1, $_GET['image_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query -> bindParam(1, $ip_address, PDO::PARAM_INT);                          
$rowsa = $pdo->execute();
$up = "";
$down = "";

if(!empty($rowsa[0]["vote_rank"])) {
   $vote_rank = $row[0]["vote_rank"];
   if($vote_rank == -1) {
       $up = "enabled";
       $down = "disabled";
   }
if($vote_rank == 1) {
       $up = "disabled";
       $down = "enabled";
}
}
```

Comment: What's the error you're seeing? is there any logging you can share?

Comment: The title of the thread..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`execute` is a method of the `PDOStatement` class ([see docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)), not of `PDO`. The return value of `PDO::prepare` is an instance of `PDOStatement`, so replace `$pdo->execute();` with `$query->execute();`

The `bindParam` calls also seem incorrect to me, as [the docs say](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) on the first argument (`$parameter`):

> Parameter identifier. For a prepared statement using named placeholders, this will be a parameter name of the form :name. For a prepared statement using question mark placeholders, this will be the 1-indexed position of the parameter.

This means that this:

```
$query -> bindParam(1, $_GET['image_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query -> bindParam(1, $ip_address, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Should be:

```
$query->bindParam(1, $_GET['image_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindParam(2, $ip_address, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: Yes, I just got that error for wrong number of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Prepare returns the object you need to execute so your code should be:

```
$stmt= $pdo->prepare("SELECT SUM(vote_rank) as vote_rank FROM ipaddress_vote_map WHERE image_id = ? and ip_address = ?");
$stmt-> bindParam(1, $_GET['image_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt-> bindParam(2, $ip_address, PDO::PARAM_INT);                          
$rowsa = $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: No problem, I have plenty of moments, by the way once you understand prepared statements take a look at this: https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class   - it's a lot prettier and easier to use.

Comment: @stan: Check the second part of my answer, on the issues with `PDOStatement::bindParam`, this answer still contains a bug. That explains the _"Invalid parameter number"_ error you're getting